# Function to limit data by date and get growth

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a dataset that has the following:

```
 Customer_ID| Region| Sales_Date| Sales_Amount
 183984     | 1     | 01-04-23  | 1232.44
 183991     | 2     | 01-04-23  | 23.41
 128943     | 1     | 01-04-23  | 7562.22
```

Goal: Understand the sales growth by region comparing current 4 weeks over previous 4 weeks.

Attempt:

I created dynamic time variables, split the dataset by the times and then aggregated by region. Then manually calculated growth. I want to know how to simplify this.

```
current_date = datetime(2023, 4, 8)

current_4_wks_start = current_date
current_4_wks_end   = current_date - timedelta(weeks=4)
past_4_wks_start = current_4_wks_end - timedelta(weeks=1)
past_4_wks_end = past_4_wks_start - timedelta(weeks=4)

sales_current_weeks = df_sales_ytd[(df_sales_ytd['Sales_Date'] >= current_4_wks_start) & (df_sales_ytd['Sales_Date'] <= current_4_wks_end)]
sales_current_weeks = sales_current_weeks.groupby(['Region']).agg({'Total_Sales':'sum'}).reset_index().rename(columns = {'Total_Sales': 'current_4_nrx'})

sales_previous_weeks = df_sales_ytd[(df_sales_ytd['Sales_Date'] >= current_4_wks_start) & (df_sales_ytd['Sales_Date'] <= current_4_wks_end)]
sales_previous_weeks = sales_previous_weeks .groupby(['Region']).agg({'Total_Sales':'sum'}).reset_index().rename(columns = {'Total_Sales': 'previous_4_nrx'})

df_4_growth = pd.merge(sales_current_weeks,sales_previous_weeks , on = 'Region', how='inner')
df_4_growth['growth_4'] = (df_4_growth['previous_4_nrx']-df_4_growth['current_4_nrx'])/(df_4_growth['previous_4_nrx']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this process by creating a function to filter the data and perform the aggregation based on the given date ranges.

```
def sales_by_region(df, start_date, end_date):
    sales = df[(df['Sales_Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Sales_Date'] <= end_date)]
    sales = sales.groupby(['Region']).agg({'Sales_Amount': 'sum'}).reset_index()
    return sales
```

The above function `sales_by_region` takes a DataFrame, start date, and end date as inputs and returns the aggregated sales by region for that date range. This function can be used to calculate sales for the current and previous 4 weeks. Then, the growth can be calculated and added to the resulting data frame.

Comment: is there a way to combine previous and current into this? So pass 4 dates as parameters?

Comment: You can. I generally don't prefer having more than 2-3 parameters on a function. It generally means that something is not correct. But there can be exceptions.